# Flutter 3des encryption

Tags: flutter, encryption, cryptography, 3des

I need some help with successfully implementing 3des encryption on my flutter project, heres what i have and i dont know where i could be going wrong.
Following the documentation on https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_3des I get

```
java.security.InvalidException: Wrong Key Size.
void doEncryption() async {
String key = "Seaxveqnxpqt0q2w";
String string = "3056775474;011";
var _encrypt = await Flutter3des.encrypt(string, key, iv: iv)
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my implementation.
[image: Console Message]

Comment: Maybe the library can only handle 24 bytes keys. In this case you would have to extend your [2TDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) 16 bytes key to a 24 bytes key yourself by appending the first 8 bytes: `Seaxveqnxpqt0q2wSeaxveqn`.

Comment: Why would you user such an insecure, broken cipher? Because of CN?

Comment: @Ber- The API I'm trying to implement requires it, so that's why.

Comment: @Tppaco, this did not seem to work either, I'll keep trying to find a solution, Thanks for your response, and if perhaps you stumble on a solution please do reach out. Apparently, the encryption worked on this platform https://onepipe.io/tools/encryptor/Home/Encrypt without issues, still don't know-how.

Comment: Besides a 24 bytes key, a _hex encoded_ key and IV (the latter, by the way, is missing in your snippet) are also needed: `String key = hex.encode(utf8.encode("Seaxveqnxpqt0q2wSeaxveqn")); String iv = hex.encode(utf8.encode("01234567"));` (for the libraries see e.g. [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/Utf8Codec-class.html) and [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/convert/latest/convert/HexCodec-class.html)). Then encryption works. You can also find an [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_3des#implementation) in the library description.

Comment: Don't use 3DES it's not good enough in 2022.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco it works just as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

My friend your key is 16 byte
this algorithm required 24 byte key for encryption
use this as a sample
static const _key = "702040801020305070B0D1101020305070B0D1112110D0B0";